# Dificuldade para somar valores. (SQL)

Tags: sql, query, select, group-by, sum

Estou fazendo uma consulta SQL onde preciso levantar e somar com o intuito de filtrar o valor total que um fornecedor nos vendeu este ano. Porém, imagino eu que por conta da data não ser um campo repetido, os valores não se somam, gerando muitas linhas;

Obs.: Nenhum dos campos é chave.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT B.FOR_RAZAO, SUM(A.ENT_VALOR)  AS VALOR
    FROM TABELA_ENTRADA A
    INNER JOIN TABELA_FORNECEDOR B
    ON A.ENT_FORNECEDOR = B.for_codigo
    WHERE ENT_DATA BETWEEN '01.01.2022' AND '21.11.2022'
    GROUP BY B.FOR_RAZAO, A.ENT_VALOR, A.ENT_DATA;
```

[Preciso evitar que a coluna FOR_RAZAO não traga repetições.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTMVr.png)

Comment: *"total que um fornecedor nos vendeu este ano"* nesse caso deve agrupar pelo ano da data e não a data toda, ou senão irá gerar muitas somas, ou simplesmente remover o ano do group e filtrar no where, por exemplo `YEAR(A.ENT_DATA) = 2021`. No seu exemplo a data no `group by` é inútil, pq está filtrando as datas dentro do mesmo ano, então não é necessário agrupar

Comment: Ainda assim o meu problema persiste (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTMVr.png) eu preciso que o campo FOR_RAZAO não se repita na consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa colocar as colunas A.ENT_VALOR (que é a que você está somando), nem  A.ENT_DATA (que não aparece no resultado) no group by, e o distinct é desnecessário.

```
SELECT B.FOR_RAZAO, SUM(A.ENT_VALOR)  AS VALOR
FROM TABELA_ENTRADA A
INNER JOIN TABELA_FORNECEDOR B
ON A.ENT_FORNECEDOR = B.for_codigo
WHERE ENT_DATA BETWEEN '01.01.2022' AND '21.11.2022'
GROUP BY B.FOR_RAZAO;
```